# Extend last li to remaining width of a ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have been puzzled about this for a while now. Here is what i have now:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   |                  |                     |
|       Item 1      |      Item 2      |      Last item      |
|                   |                  |                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There, the last li is only taking up part of the ul. I need it to look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   |                  |                                      |
|       Item 1      |      Item 2      |              Last item               |
|                   |                  |                                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can not use Javascript (or Jquery).
I do not want to set the width of each li, since the text size could vary, and i do not know how many li's there will be. I might have 5 or 3.'

How would i accomplish this? Thanks.

**Here is a jsfiddle with some of my code. I need the lighter color to expand the rest of the ul. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xZeJt/)**

Comment: Could you write a small test case using jsfiddle plz?

Comment: Copy-paste the relevant markup you have so far to the question, and if possible use a site like http://jsfiddle.net to provide a live demo.

Comment: If you want all li's to have the same width, except the last one (without specifying any widths), this won't be possible with just CSS.

Comment: @Juhana I edited it with a JSfiddle.

Comment: Please indicate the browsers (and versions) your code should support also. I don't think IE<8 supports selectors like `last-child`, `last-of-type` etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can float all elements but the last to the left.

The last element's box model will then extend behind these floated list items (even though the content doesn't). `overflow:hidden` will prevent this behaviour; the box model will begin when the last floated item ends, as if the floated items were still in the natural flow of the page.

```css
ul, li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul li{
    display: block;
    float:left;
}

ul li:last-child{
    background-color: #ddd;

    float:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>I will extend to the end of the page.. No matter how far. I will also not drop beneath my previous items, even if the text in here requires me to span over multiple lines.</li>    
</ul>
```

An edit of your newly added JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZeJt/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Will this work if i have another ul in side a li...like a ticker of some sorts?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This may be a separate question, but how come it doesn't work if I apply a css class to the last `li` element?

Comment: Brilliant... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ul>li:last-of-type {width:whatever}
```

So the two li's before the last would float:left and have 20% on both and the last one can have 60%;

Also don't forgot to clear the flaots with

```
ul {overflow:auto;}
```

and keep the % perfect so the borders do not escape:

```
ul>li {box-sizing:border-box;}
```