# How to get full input width for primefaces autocomplete(multiple="true")

Tags: css, primefaces

How to get full input width for primefaces autocomplete(multiple="true").

[ShowCase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml)

[image: There is an issue]

Comment: What css did you try?

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried a lot of cases. No success. I thought maybe somebody already did it.

Comment: Maybe if you posted the client-side html (the more important part) and tag it html instead of PrimeFaces, you'll reach more people with relevant knowledge. If you have the css/html solution, backport to the xhtml. JSF is in this regard merely an html generator. And please, always post what you tried. It isasier to comment on that than to provide a full solution (if people do not by accident have one)

Comment: Found solution right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027764/extend-last-li-to-remaining-width-of-a-ul). Thanks.